# ReactJS Slider carousel component

Tags: reactjs, slider, react-component

Following some code examples, I've found this:

```
<Slider ref = {c => (this.slider = c)} {...this.settings}>
        {
          //custom component for slider content
        }
      </Slider>
```

I don't get what's the meaning of `ref = {c => (this.slider = c)} {...this.settings}`. What is this doing? `this.settings` is an object with various properties, like `arrows:false`, `mobilefirst:true`. But I don't know this construct of ref etc. and in the example is not explained.
Is there a guide for this?

Comment: This might be helpful for you https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code creates reference to the element to work with it later - it is stored on the class and can be accessed with this.slider or passed down as a prop to children. For example, it can be used to set focus just like with regular HTML element: this.slider.focus(). You can read more about callback refs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs